# Jenkins Multibranch Pipleine: set _job_ name from Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

**Short**: Can I set the name of a Jenkins **job** created automatically by the Multibranch Pipeline job, to something calculated in the job itself?

**Long**:
We do a lot of microservices with mostly identical build processes, and we would like to have as little hassle building and testing them as we can.

To that end, I am considering the Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline jobs, where I could just add another project repository and have that new repository built with new jobs being created for new branches that contain `Jenkinsfile`s. That would also cause the new jobs appear on the build monitor. And here is where the problems start.

I would like to see the name of the project on the build monitor cells, rather than something like `my_multibranch_pipeline_t » temp_branch_one`. However, I couldn't find a way to set the JOB_NAME to anything.

Am I missing something?

Comment: So far, looks like what I need is the Job DSL job generator.

Comment: An alternative is to fork the jenkins multi-branch plugin and override the job-naming logic, the hardest part being finding it, possibly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know any way to set the job name from the Jenkinsfile. However we solve the same issue that you describe using [seedjobs](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Tutorial---Using-the-Jenkins-Job-DSL). These are basically freestyle jobs executing Jenkins' [Job DSL](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/), which is able to define as many jobs as you like.

We are using a map of service names, mapped to their Git-urls and iterate over that using Groovy's `each`.